# checkbox data binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, database

How to add a check box in a .aspx page.
I had used a database. and i read data from the database successfully.
And now the readed data is in data table "dt". And i added this statement

```
if (dt.Rows[0]["IsActive"].ToString() == "True")
```

if the condition is true, Then the check box will be checked?
but i didn't get. How it will get?

Comment: You should post some code to show us how you are setting the value :). My guess is that you should put myCheckbox.Checked = (bool)dt.Rows[0]["IsActive"], but it is hard to tell where you need this code o be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (dt.Rows[0]["IsActive"].ToString() == "True")
{
     chkAvtive.Checked = true;
}
```

chkActive is the id of your checkbox. Assuming the checkbox was already in the controls list in the page.

You can add a checkbox to your page using the following code

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkActive" runat="server">
```

Comment: You mistyped the Checked property. It should be chkActive.Checked